# how to open a specific page using servlet?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

How to open specific page using servlet ? like facebook when user enter email and password then their own fb page open. 
My project is employee activity monitoring. 
When employee login then must be open their own page not other. 
Pls help me.

Comment: Use the servlet to open the page, then in this page make your control to make your page personalized for each user.

Answer (score 1):

The most common requirement after a login page is a redirect to the appropriate page instead of a forward. With a forward, you ask a JSP (or any other servlet) to display itself *in same request* -> the URL in top browser line is still the login URL

With a redirect, the servlet issue a special response to browser asking it to make a new request to another URL -> it costs an additional request but the displayed URL in browser is the correct one.

In you servlet it is just :

```
response.sendRedirect("/path/toPage?user=xyz");
```

or any other URL you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`RequestDispatcher.forward()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse)) to forward the request to your new page.

```
 getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("yourPage.jsp").forward 
       (req, res);
```

Then in your new page you can write your control to handle the request make a personalized response for each user.

You can check [**Calling JSP from servlet**](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=176) tutorial for further details.

Comment: This does not change the url though, it just loads the contents

Comment: @OrestesKappaAs I stated in comments in the OP, this will be used to only forward the `request`, then it should be handled in the new page. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

considering your request to be a login request to a loginservlet, it can respond in 2 ways,

1.Generate the response itself (html code in pritwriter)

2. Redirect to another resource (like a html or jsp)

If your user specific page has a common template, but just needs some specific values to change then you can use 1st approach
else if each user has custom UI (highly unlikely) then forward it using requestDispacther